# How do I understand the $\|a\|$ used in this equation which describes the force by linear springs between two particles?

Tags: normed-spaces, physics

I have the following equation:

$ F_{i j}^{e}(x)=k_{i j}\left(\left\|\mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j}\right\|-l_{i j}\right) \frac{\mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j}}{\left\|\mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j}\right\|} $

from this paper [http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/ReadingSeminar/Papers/Magnenat-Thalmann04.pdf](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emisha/ReadingSeminar/Papers/Magnenat-Thalmann04.pdf) on cloth simulation, it occurs on page 19. I just wanted to clarify what the meaning behind this equation would be.

So I believe it is saying that the Force between particles i and j is equal to the k constant multiplied by $ \left\|\mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j}\right\|-l_{i j} $ , which I would assume to be the distance (magnitude) between two particles, i and j, take away the rest length. But then in the fraction I can see that there is also $ \mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j} $, so without the ||, and I can't tell the difference in meaning between $ \mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j} $ and $ ||\mathbf{x}_{i}-\mathbf{x}_{j} || $ . I've looked for the meaning of || || in mathematics, but it appears to have many meanings, including the norm but in this context I am unsure as I haven't cowered norms in the limited university maths modules (I had one) and I don't really know how it applies here after looking for the definition. Could someone clarify?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a force, and typically the force is not just a real number, it also usually has a direction.  That's what the $x_i-x_j$ is contributing. All the other quantities appearing combined to form a coefficient in front of the vector $x_i-x_j$.

I can't see anything to suggest that $\|\cdot\|$ means anything other than the [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space#Euclidean_norm) on real vectors.

Comment: I would add that $\frac{\mathbf d}{\lVert\mathbf d\rVert}$ is the unit vector parallel to $\mathbf d$; or, its direction without its magnitude. (These things are obvious to us, but perhaps not to Hugh.)

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes: glad you highlighted it.